# What do time members mean in JOB_INFO_2?

Tags: windows, winapi, printing, spooler

The [`JOB_INFO_2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145020%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, which tells you a lot about a print job.

I understand quite well the `Submitted` member, because it's a `SYSTEMTIME`. But what are `StartTime` and `Untiltime`, which are `DWORD`s?

Specifically, I want a printjob to print only after a certain time, for which I'm going to set `StartTime` and call [`SetJob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162978%28VS.85%29.aspx). But to what do I need to set that field? Is it a number of seconds since something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET is often handy to get better documentation.  This field is exposed without any conversion by the PrintSystemJobInfo.StartTimeOfDay property.  Documented as:

> Gets the earliest time of day,
>   expressed as the number of minutes
>   after midnight Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC) (also called Greenwich Mean
>   Time [GMT]), that the print job can
>   begin printing.